# Clustering similar people using distance matrix in r

Tags: r, correlation, clustering, distance

I have 2,000 people with 60 features, the feature are highly correlated.
I can't remove the correlated features in my case: I need all the data.
I want to group similar people using a clustering algorithm.

I have tried:

1. `k-means` using Euclidean distance on "max-min" normalized data:
   the distribution between the group was somewhat even.
2. `h-clust` using mahalanobis distance on Moore-Penrose generalized Inverse matrix of the data:
   the distribution between the group was not good (more then half was in one group and all the other had very little people in it (1 or 2 people in some).

From what I have read for correlated data, it is best to compute distance using mahalanobis distance, but the result was very odd.

Did I compute it right?

Do you have other suggestion to cluster the people when the data is correlated?

Comment: How many PC's does it take to account for 95% of the variation?

Comment: @generic_user how can I know that? it's in the function "kmeans" and "hclust"?

Comment: There is a close link between mahalanobis distance and principal components analysis.  I'd suggest that you read up on it.  Basically you determine the orthogonal directions in your dataset that successively explain the most variability.  In R, the function `prcomp` implements it.  But without reading up, you'll have no idea how to interpret the output.

Comment: @generic_user i know what is pca, i thouth it for dimenality reduction. I need at the end for every id what class he is belong to. anyhow if i got this result on mahalanobis distance wont I get the same in pca? I have tried in the past to use PCA and it didn't work, I though its because of the correlated data.

Comment: @generic_user ,did computation of mahalanobis distance was right?

Comment: What do you mean PCA "didn't work"?  If your first few PC's account for almost all of the variation, then you might consider clustering only on those (derived) varibles.

Comment: @generic_user if I don't want to use pca is there  another way? did computation of mahalanobis distance was right?

Comment: I don't know without knowing more about your context.  Sometimes clustering is very difficult, and doesn't work cleanly.

Comment: First, tell us your context.  Second, tell us why you can't remove variables - my suggestion would be that you do remove a lot of variables.  Third, there is no way for us to know if you computed M distance correctly, as you didn't say what you did. Fourth, the cluster solution may not have been what you wanted, but it may be what the data show.

Comment: Also, please add a plot of the first two PCs, so we get a impression of how the data looks like.